# delete records from dataframe where any of the column is null or empty

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, record, is-empty

Is there any method where we can delete the records from a dataframe where any of the column values is null or empty?

```
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|id |zipcode|type    |city               |state|population|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
|1  |704    |STANDARD|                   |PR   |30100     |
|2  |704    |        |PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|PR   |          |
|3  |76166  |UNIQUE  |CINGULAR WIRELESS  |TX   |84000     |
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------+
```

I want output to be:

```
+---+-------+------+-----------------+-----+----------+
|id |zipcode|type  |city             |state|population|
+---+-------+------+-----------------+-----+----------+
|4  |76166  |UNIQUE|CINGULAR WIRELESS|TX   |84000     |
+---+-------+------+-----------------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Try this: `df_name.na.drop()
    .show(false)`

Comment: Thanks it worke. Can you please help me on the below mentioned post: It will be a great help. Thanks in advance.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815514/remove-null-array-field-from-dataframe-while-converting-it-to-json

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df
  .na.replace(df.columns,Map("" -> null)) // convert empty strings with null
  .na.drop() // drop nulls and NaNs
  .show()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you help me in the below mentioned post. Thanks in Advance.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815514/remove-null-array-field-from-dataframe-while-converting-it-to-json

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_name.na.drop()
  .show(false)
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: It worked. Can you please help me with this below mentioned post.                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815514/remove-null-array-field-from-dataframe-while-converting-it-to-json